# Extract a flat list of dependencies from Bazel file

Tags: java, maven, bazel

Is there a library out there to extract the following dependencies as a flat list, or would something have to be custom written?

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_jar")

def include_java_deps():

  http_jar(
      name = "com_google_inject_guice",
      sha256 = "b378ffc35e7f7125b3c5f3a461d4591ae1685e3c781392f0c854ed7b7581d6d2",
      url = "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/inject/guice/4.0/guice-4.0.jar",
  )

  http_jar(
      name = "org_sonatype_sisu_inject_cglib",
      sha256 = "42e1dfb26becbf1a633f25b47e39fcc422b85e77e4c0468d9a44f885f5fa0be2",
      url = "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/sonatype/sisu/inject/cglib/2.2.1-v20090111/cglib-2.2.1-v20090111.jar",
  )

  http_jar(
      name = "javax_inject_javax_inject",
      sha256 = "91c77044a50c481636c32d916fd89c9118a72195390452c81065080f957de7ff",
      url = "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/inject/javax.inject/1/javax.inject-1.jar",   
  )
```

This should be the desired output, extracting a flat list of the dependencies and concatenating the respective version.

```
com.google.inject:guice@4.0
org.sonatype.sisu.inject:cglib@2.2.1-v20090111
javax.inject:javax.inject@1
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `bazel sync` can help here. Via this command, you can create a resolved file (e.g. `resolved.bzl`)

```
bazel sync --experimental_repository_resolved_file=resolved.bzl
```

This file is a .json file. With content similar to this:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "rule_class": "@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl%http_archive",
        "attributes": {
            "url": "",
            "urls": [
                "https://github.com/embree/embree/archive/v2.16.5.zip"
            ],
            "sha256": "9c4c0c385a7725946648578c1b58e887caa8b4a675a9356e76b9501d9e2e9e42",
            "netrc": "",
            "auth_patterns": {},
            "canonical_id": "",
            "strip_prefix": "embree-2.16.5",
            "type": "",
            "patches": [],
            "patch_tool": "",
            "patch_args": [
                "-p0"
            ],
            "patch_cmds": [],
            "patch_cmds_win": [],
            "build_file": "//ThirdParty:embree.BUILD",
            "build_file_content": "",
            "workspace_file_content": "",
            "name": "embree"
        },
        "output_tree_hash": "b96d3a8db2ddd4bbc7ccde297a1d12e8be48c768bddde1ade53a4987861a1fe7"
    }
]
```